# How to join 2 views in mysql?

Tags: mysql, view, outer-join

I have 2 views with columns,

```
view1 = (ID, Number)
view2 = (ID, Number, Name)
```

How to create select display such that

```
Display = (ID, Number, Name)
```

and Display is the FULL OUTER JOIN view1 and view2.

Comment: I reject the premise of the question ;-). Why do you have views

Comment: @Strawberry the two different views are the simplified forms of multiple tables. Now, I need to join them.

Comment: @pnkjmndhl You join them the same way you join ordinary tables. That's one of the points of using views, you can (mostly) treat them like tables.

Comment: @barmar The only problem is that MySQL doesnot support Full outer join for views.

Comment: @pnkjmndhl It doesn't support full outer join for tables, either. You emulate it for views the same way you emulate it for ordinary tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT view2.*
FROM   view1
       LEFT JOIN view 2
           ON view1.id = view2.id
UNION

SELECT view2.*
FROM   view1
       RIGHT JOIN view 2
           ON view1.id = view2.id
```

Comment: I need a full outer join. Thanks.

Comment: edited to reflect

Comment: There has to be a simpler way to do this.

Comment: MySql does not support Full outer join

Comment: Please mark as the answer if this worked